# Disable Power Management in Fedora 12

Tags: linux, lcd, fedora, power-management, fedora-12

How to disable the power management in fedora 12, so that lcd/monitor should not go to sleep/off when system is idle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following are commands to successfully disable the Power Management in Fedora

The following will set DPMS(Display Power Management Signaling) parameters

> xset dpms 0 0 0

The three zero values represent three different modes

> First zero disables the standby mode
>
> Second zero disables the suspend mode
>
> Third zero disables the force mode

The following will disable the screensaver

> xset s off

For details please see

> man xset

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to just disable this sometimes?

What desktop environment are you using? Gnome has [Gnome-power-manager](http://projects.gnome.org/gnome-power-manager/), which allows you to control how the monitor behaves when the machine is idle.  In KDE, [powerdevil](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=85078&forumpage=3&PHPSESSID=5bcc6a64551a3931798e90b37fbb0a7b) is part of the base, so opening the systems settings (Advanced tab) should get you to the power management settings.

An extreme approach would be to turn off APM and ACPI completely. Turning off APM and ACPI will disable all power management on your computer - on a laptop, you are going to kill your battery performance. That said...

To do it only once:

1. When you first start your computer, you get the GRUB screen. Press `ESC`.
2. Add `apm=off acpi=off` to the end of the line that appears, and press enter. 
     If acpi=on exists, then delete it.

If that works, you can make it permanent:

1. Become root (su -)
2. Edit /etc/grub.conf
3. At the end of the line that starts with kernel, add `apm=off acpi=off` (remove acpi=on)
4. Save & restart.

Comment: no effect of apm=off acpi=off. same behaviour as before.

Comment: what window manager & desktop environment are you using?